# Jasper Report Not Responding With Exception "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(AffineTransform.java:815)
    at sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.initFontData(StandardGlyphVector.java:1136)
    at sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.init(StandardGlyphVector.java:1115)
    at sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.(StandardGlyphVector.java:172)
    at java.awt.Font.getStringBounds(Font.java:2421)
    at java.awt.Font.getStringBounds(Font.java:2331)
    at java.awt.Font.getStringBounds(Font.java:2365)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.SimpleTextLineWrapper.measureParagraphFragment(SimpleTextLineWrapper.java:729)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.SimpleTextLineWrapper.measureLine(SimpleTextLineWrapper.java:586)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.SimpleTextLineWrapper.nextLine(SimpleTextLineWrapper.java:524)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderNextLine(TextMeasurer.java:704)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:507)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:448)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:621)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillStaticText.prepare(JRFillStaticText.java:187)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:331)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:384)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:347)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillFixedBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2097)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnFooter(JRVerticalFiller.java:997)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1920)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1968)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:754)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:849)
    at punetaxi.User.PrintPassTkt(User.java:1861)
    at punetaxi.User.jButton3ActionPerformed(User.java:1662)

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector is spending to much time and resources and recovering very little heap memory in return.
2 possible solutions :

1.Give some more Heap-memory to the Java-Engine (-Xmx) but this only helps, if the application needs exactly as much memory, as the heap-limit before was set. So try this first.

2.You can turn this off with the command line option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

Note: To increase heap size - You can add a system environment variable named _JAVA_OPTIONS, and set the heap size values there.
For example if you want a 512Mb initial and 1024Mb maximum heap size you could use:

WINDOWS:

SET _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms512m -Xmx1024m

LINUX:

export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"